# I can't run cordova according to the CLI documentation

Tags: cordova

I was following the cordova CLI documentation and after I ran the install

```
npm install -g cordova@5.0.0
```

It returns:

```
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.9.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} 
(current: {"node":"0.12.4","npm":"2.10.1"})
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} 
(current: {"node":"0.12.4","npm":"2.10.1"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"}
(current: {"node":"0.12.4","npm":"2.10.1"})
npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, 
but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
C:\Users\Lee\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova ->  
C:\Users\Lee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova   
cordova@5.0.0 C:\Users\Lee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
+-- underscore@1.7.0
+-- q@1.0.1
+-- nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
+-- cordova-lib@5.0.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, 
    properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11,  
    unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0, rc@0.5.2, 
    dep-graph@1.1.0, through2@0.6.3, npmconf@0.1.16, xcode@0.6.7, 
    elementtree@0.1.5, d8@0.4.4, init-package-json@1.6.0, tar@1.0.2,
    glob@4.0.6, request@2.47.0, cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.8,  
    cordova-app-hello-world@3.9.0, plist@1.1.0,  cordova-js@3.9.0,   
    npm@1.3.4)
```

I added the directory to my PATH env variable, then typed `cordova` to see if it would run (according to the CLI it should print `help info`)

But it errors out and the pop up dialog box complains about line 23 of `cordova.js`, which is

```
var cordova_lib = require('cordova-lib');
```

So I am dead in the water and don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have Node.js and look what error you have, you need to update your node version with `npm cache clean
npm update -g`

EDIT : Yeah it seems to be an older version so you can download a stable version [here](http://blog.nodejs.org/2015/01/26/node-v0-10-36-stable/)

Comment: I have node.js installed.  From the error message it appears to be a newer version than what cordova expects

Comment: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.4","npm":"2.10.1"})

Comment: oh yeah my bad i edited and give you a link, just uninstall your node then install this one